# Single application, different domains and serve differents index.html in nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx

i have react app with nginx, I would to like to serve 2 different index.html with depends on ending of domain. There is my code:

```
server {
 listen 80;

 location ~ clientfirst\.eu {
  add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
  expires 0;
  root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index clientFirst.html clientFirst.htm;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /clientFirst.html;
 }

 location / {
  add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
  expires 0;
  root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index clientSecond.html clientSecond.htm;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /clientSecond.html;
 }

 error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

 location = /50x.html {
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
 }
}
```

If the domain has ends with clientfirst.eu I want to show clientFirst index.html otherwise clientSecond.html. How Can I write this condition or what should I correct here?

Comment: Are you talking about different domain, or just different routes on the same domain? If it's different domains, you normally make two different server blocks. If you are talking about different routes, `/` is the base route, and `/someroute` would be the location for the other route.

Comment: See [how Nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) to understand the `server` and `location` block hierarchy.